# Database design for Social network friends list, friends circle, post sharing

Tags: database-design, social-networking

I want user to view by recent Post in the order they were posted, but only if the user that created the post gave the user permission to view them. Much like google+ circle list.

Here is my original design, any suggestion on improvement, would be appreciated.

```
USER
Id
Name
...


POST
Id
Message
IsCloseFriendCanView
IsFamilyCanView
IsAcquaintanceCanView
IsDisabledComment
IsPostLock
CreatedByUserId
Created_Time
LastComment_Time 
...

POST_COMMENT
Id
PostId
Message
CreatedByUserId
Created_Time


FRIEND
Id
UserId
FriendUserId
IsCloseFriend
IsFamily
IsAcquaintance
IsBlocked
....

FRIEND_LIST (custom friends list only)
Id
UserId (owner)
FriendId
FriendListTypeId

FRIEND_LIST_TYPE 
Id
UserId
Name
...

POST_FRIEND (CAN VIEW)
Id
PostId
FriendId
....


POST_FRIEND_LIST (CAN VIEW - custom)
Id
PostId
FriendListTypeId
....
```

EDIT: updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but seems you will also need a table holding the relation between user and friends

e.g.

```
FRIEND
user_id
friend_id
close_friend
```

And on POST you would need something to identify whether it is visible to "All Friends","Close Friends" or "Public".

Then assuming $this_user is a logged in user or some dummy value e.g. -1 if not logged in, you can select a list of valid posts which will show

1. posts created by the logged in user
2. posts created by friends of the logged in user visible to all friends
3. posts created by friends of the logged in user visible to close friends
4. posts set as public

using something like

```
select p.id, p.message, 
  from POST p
 where createdbyuserid=$this_user 
    or (visible='F' 
        and exists (select 1 
                 from friend f 
                where p.createdbyuserid=f.user_id 
                  and f.friend_id=$this_user)
       )
    or (visible='C' 
        and exists (select 1 
                 from friend f 
                where p.createdbyuserid=f.user_id 
                  and f.friend_id=$this_user
                  and f.close_friend='Y')
       )
    or (visible='P')
 order by created_time
```

If no user is logged in, then $this_user would be set to -1 so only the public posts would be visible.

Then you use the result from this select to get the relevant comments for each post in a subsequent select.

Comment: cool, I think your way is better than mine :) so we dont need post_view then? What about conditions where you can share with friends and exclude friends John, Alice etc..

Comment: The share with friends should be handled by having an entry in the FRIEND table.  Facebook added a feature for close friends so to mimic this, you could add a flag in the friend table for close friend Y or N and then on the POST table, have three visible options.  I've amended the SQL in the original answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks Trevor, ok let me understand this abit, how would you meet the condition where visible to all friends expect for john, bob, and alice Or Specific to friends X, Y,Z except for Q,R,S. or All friends except for groupZ, friend A,B,C.

Comment: If you need to exclude specific people, are you intending to do this for each post ? Then the person creating the post would need to specify which individuals can see it in which case, you probably do want a POST_VIEW table as you originally suggested with post_id and friend_Id. Join the post to this table based on the logged in user being the friend.  The previous suggestion is based on you selecting a subset of friends and then allowing those to see more than others so your original idea of a POST_VIEW.  You can do a select of all friends and then use minus to exclude specific sets.

Comment: See update, above, what about two post view tables, one for post view for friend, the other post view for friend list, somehow can we just have 1 post view table?

Comment: 001, can you perhaps update the question to make your requirements more specific? The answer Trevor North provided originally seems to reflect the way FB and Google+ do things, as per your original question.

Comment: @TrevorNorth I updated it once again, with a modification of your suggestion, i think its pretty much done and can meet the original requirements. What do you think?

Comment: I think from the new table POST_CONDITION and FRIEND_LIST that each user can define their own lists and then when they create a post, they will choose which of those lists are allowed or excluded from viewing the post and you will populate the POST_CONDITION with the list of friend_ids.  So you will not retain the chosen list ID against the post.  So what happens if i have a list called "Old School Friends" and i add someone to that list - you cant add that friend to the posts i already allowed "Old School Friends" to see so they will only see new posts that i assign for that list.

Comment: Same would apply for removing someone from the list. If thats the intention then the model is fine but if you want additions/removals from the list to get permissions, then add friend_list_id to the POST_CONDITION instead of the actual friend_id and in the lookup join POST_CONDITION to the FRIEND_LIST talbe to get the list of current users in the list who have permission.

Comment: @TrevorNorth what about if we just removed POST_CONDITION all together and have POST_FRIEND and POST_FRIEND_LIST, which is the same as the original POST_VIEW. Now it will be like google+, you can either include friends/friendslist to view or not include them at all.

Comment: See POST table above, it was updated to include default can view flags.

Comment: So long as you can determine the SQL to fetch the sets of POST based on the different cases e.g. friend logs in on exclude list, friend logs in on include list, non friend logs in, then the model should be fine but make sure you define the queries and then create the DB and test it before writing the front end.  Good luck with it.